# How to align printed data frames automatically to left in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

In the below MWE, I set the alignment of print() manually to right at the chunk level (the latter chunk); how can this be set to be universal in the whole R Markdown document?

```
---
output: html_document
---
```

````markdown
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

### Aligned to right (the default)

````markdown
```{r} 
head(iris, n=1)
```
````

```r
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

### Aligned to left

````markdown
``` r
print(head(iris, n=1), right = FALSE)
```
````

```
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1 5.1          3.5         1.4          0.2         setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a new `print.data.frame` method inside your setup chunk:

```r
print.data.frame <- function(x, ...) {
  base::print.data.frame(x, ..., right = FALSE)
}
```

So that you subsequently get the desired behaviour in the rest of your document:

```r
head(iris, n = 1)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1 5.1          3.5         1.4          0.2         setosa
```

Comment: Nice solution. However, at least in my system, the required subsequent command is `print(head(iris, n=1))`. Calling the dataset straight with `head(iris, n=1)` does not lead to the desired output.

Comment: @jaggedjava that's odd. The new method should be invoked without having to specify `print`.

Comment: Did you run the MWE in R Markdown? Could it be version-specific behavior?

Comment: Regardless, the solution is guaranteed to work with the additional print() command. I have accepted the solution - thanks indeed.